# R: subset many objects efficiently

Tags: r, subset

I very often use logical vectors to subset other vectors, matrices and data frames (in the genomics field, it's very common). 
On such vector would be made like so:

```
condition <- myNucleotideVector == "G"
```

then I work on subsets matching that condition. So I often end up with clumsy code like:

```
myNucleotideVector <- myNucleotideVector[condition]
object2 <- object2[condition]
dataframe1 <- dataframe1[conditon,]
```

or

```
result <- myNucleotideVector[condition] - object2[condition] + dataframe1[conditon,2]
```

which repeats `[condition]` many times.
I could put all vectors of same size and a data frame and subset it, but I don't always want to do it (in particular given the length of vectors, which can be millions).

I'm looking for an efficient solution. For the first case quoted above, I thought about a function that takes any object provided as argument and subsets it. 
That would look like

```
subsetObjects <- function(..., condition, env = globalenv()) {          
    call <- as.character(match.call())
    names <- call[2:(length(call)-1)] #this isn't ideal as it doesn't consider the case where one would place 'condition' argument before the objects to subset
    for (name in names) {    
        value <- get(name, envir = env)
        assign(name, subset(value, subset = condition),envir = env)
    }
}
```

As you see in the comment, it isn't perfect. Maybe someone can suggest something more efficient.

For the second case, I'm looking for something similar to `with()`, in which every vector, matrix or data frame would be automatically subset according to the condition. That would look like

```
result <- withCondition(condition, expression)
```

If no such function exist, I could write my own, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks

Jean

Comment: why not just use something like `lapply(list_of_matrices, function(x) x[condition, ])` ?? or even easier: `lapply(list_of_matrices, subset, vector == "C")` , though I am not sure I unterstand 100 % what you want, one clear example from start to finish would help

Comment: Doing so would first require creating a list of objects and then retrieving objects from the list, and I'm not much used to working with lists. But I take note.n

Comment: I want to turn `result <- myNucleotideVector[condition] - object2[condition] + dataframe1[conditon,2]` into `result <- withCondition(condition, myNucleotideVector - object2 + dataframe1[,2])` but I need an appropriate withCondition function().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea, perhaps a little unusual: Instead of working directly with the underlying objects in your code, you could create a single "getter" function which would take only one argument: the name of the variable you want to instantiate at that point in the code. You could take it as a string, or, even better, use `substitute()` to allow an unquoted symbol to be used (actually, I ended up using `as.character(substitute(var))`, so both work). Inside the function you can look up a "global condition" to decide how to subset the variable, if it should be subsetted at all. For maximum flexibility, the lookup table can also map each variable to a specific condition for that variable. Here's how I envision it:

```
## lookup table and getter
cond.to.vec <- list();
COND.NAME.GLOBAL <- '!global';
var.to.cond <- list();
cond.register <- function(name,vec=NULL) {
    prev.vec <- cond.to.vec[[name]];
    cond.to.vec[[name]] <<- vec;
    invisible(prev.vec);
};
cond.is.registered <- function(name) !is.null(cond.to.vec[[name]]);
cond.map <- function(var.name,cond.name=NULL) {
    ## remove previous mapping
    prev.mapping <- var.to.cond[[var.name]];
    var.to.cond[[var.name]] <<- NULL;
    ## omit cond.name arg to just remove
    if (is.null(cond.name)) return(invisible(prev.mapping));
    ## ensure cond.name has been registered
    if (!cond.is.registered(cond.name)) stop(paste0(cond.name,' not registered'));
    ## now add new cond.name mapping for var.name
    var.to.cond[[var.name]] <<- cond.name;
    invisible(prev.mapping);
};
cond.set <- function(var,cond.vec=NULL,sym=T) {
    var.name <- if (sym) as.character(substitute(var)) else var;
    cond.register(var.name,cond.vec);
    cond.map(var.name,if (is.null(cond.vec)) NULL else var.name);
};
cond.set.global <- function(vec=NULL) cond.register(COND.NAME.GLOBAL,vec);
cond.look.up <- function(var.name) {
    ## 1: specific condition
    cond.name <- var.to.cond[[var.name]];
    if (!is.null(cond.name)) return(cond.to.vec[[cond.name]]);
    ## 2: global condition
    vec <- cond.to.vec[[COND.NAME.GLOBAL]];
    if (!is.null(vec)) return(vec);
    ## 3: no condition
    T;
};

ss <- function(var,sym=T) {
    ## whitelist subsettables
    if (!typeof(var)%in%sapply(list(as.raw(0),T,0L,0,0i,'',list(),expression()),typeof))
        return(var);
    var.name <- if (sym) as.character(substitute(var)) else var;
    vec <- cond.look.up(var.name);
    if (length(dim(var)) == 2L) var[vec,] else var[vec];
};

## test data
set.seed(1);
N <- 10;
myNucleotideVector <- sample(c('A','C','T','G'),N,replace=T);
myNucleotideVectorNum <- sample(100:200,N,replace=T);
object2 <- seq_len(N);
dataframe1 <- data.frame(base=sample(c('A','C','T','G'),N,replace=T),x=sample(1:100,N));

## global condition
cond.set.global(myNucleotideVector == 'G');

## main code, uses global condition
result <- ss(myNucleotideVectorNum) - ss(object2) + ss(dataframe1)$x;

## register separate condition for object2
cond.set(object2,object2%%3 == 0);
result2 <- ss(myNucleotideVectorNum) - ss(object2) + ss(dataframe1)$x;

## unset/unregister all conditions to work with the entire data set
cond.set.global();
cond.set(object2);
result3 <- ss(myNucleotideVectorNum) - ss(object2) + ss(dataframe1)$x;

result;
## [1] 153 208 240
result2;
## [1] 154 208 238
result3;
##  [1] 168 175 266 153 252 208 240 203 196 206
```

---

Now we can enhance the above code with some more functions to provide a less invasive means of applying subsetting conditions:

```
ss.all.sub <- function(pt) {
    if (typeof(pt) == 'symbol') ## wrap all symbols in ss()
        as.call(list(as.symbol('ss'),pt))
    else if (typeof(pt) == 'language' && length(pt) >= 2L) ## handle function args
        as.call(c(pt[[1]], ## pass function symbol untouched
            if (as.character(pt[[1]]) == '$') ## special case for $ operator
                list(ss.all.sub(pt[[2]]),pt[[3]]) ## pass RHS untouched
            else
                lapply(pt[-1],ss.all.sub) ## recurse on all args
        ))
    else pt; ## pass literals and nullary calls untouched
};

ss.all <- function(expr) eval(ss.all.sub(substitute(expr)));

ss.with <- function(cond.arg,expr) {
    if (is.list(cond.arg)) {
        prevs <- vector('list',length(cond.arg));
        for (i in seq_along(cond.arg)) {
            name <- names(cond.arg)[i];
            prevs[i] <- list(
                if (isTRUE(name != '' && name != COND.NAME.GLOBAL))
                    cond.set(name,cond.arg[[i]],sym=F)
                else
                    cond.set.global(cond.arg[[i]])
            );
        };
    } else prev <- cond.set.global(cond.arg);
    res <- eval(ss.all.sub(substitute(expr)));
    if (is.list(cond.arg)) {
        for (i in seq_along(cond.arg)) {
            name <- names(cond.arg)[i];
            if (isTRUE(name != '' && name != COND.NAME.GLOBAL))
                cond.set(name,prevs[[i]],sym=F)
            else
                cond.set.global(prevs[[i]]);
        };
    } else cond.set.global(prev);
    res;
};

## demo parse tree substitution
ss.all.sub(substitute(myNucleotideVectorNum - object2 + dataframe1$x));
## ss(myNucleotideVectorNum) - ss(object2) + ss(dataframe1)$x

## demo using ss.with() to apply an inline condition
ss.with(myNucleotideVector == 'G',myNucleotideVectorNum - object2 + dataframe1$x);
## [1] 153 208 240
ss.with(
    list(myNucleotideVector == 'G',object2=object2%%3 == 0),
    myNucleotideVectorNum - object2 + dataframe1$x
);
## [1] 154 208 238
ss.with(T,myNucleotideVectorNum - object2 + dataframe1$x);
##  [1] 168 175 266 153 252 208 240 203 196 206
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it doesn't look like it will simplify my code much since I  would have to replace every `[condition]` with `ss()` and set global conditions.

Comment: @jeanlain See edit; I improved my answer, now I think it does exactly what you're looking for.